# Deleting specified columns daily

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to try and create a script on google sheets that automatically deletes a column of data

### I have the basics of the code setup below

function clearRange() {
var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1rhdOWeUVZKrhhkeHb8ojNQ_uisn0VzTt2ZUmwRqNihU").getSheetByName("SERVICES Department Daily Checklist");
sheetActive.getRange('H2:H3').clearContent();

```
}
```

---

I have the timed trigger set also but when i run the script it comes out with ->
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')
clearRange  @ Code.gs:3
Note** The range H2:H3 is just to test, i would like H2 and above to be deleted daily

The sheet i am using this script for has multiple tabs and i just want this to effect one of these tabs, im not sure if using H2:H3 is right as i dont know how to specify the tab.

Comment: I'm worried that the reason for your current issue of `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')` might be due to that the sheet name of "SERVICES Department Daily Checklist" might not be existing in the Spreadsheet of `1rhdOWeUVZKrhhkeHb8ojNQ_uisn0VzTt2ZUmwRqNihU`. So, how about confirming the sheet name again?